# Move values into different range if function executes correctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have two worksheets, the first uses different formulas to connect with a third party generate/verify whether an email address is valid. This happens in Column F and it uses 'domains' pasted into Column D to run the function. Anyway, once the sheet has ran all the formulas and got the results, it outputs a score between 0-1.

Now, I want all the details (Name, Email, Company, Domain) located in Columns B, C, D & F to be cleanly outputted into worksheet 2 into column B, C, D, E.

This is my code so far, but it doesn't seem to be working - not too sure.

```
function ouput(){
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Output Clean Data      to ESP').getRange('B2:E100').getValues();
  var sendex = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Email Scraper &  Verifier Custom').getRange('U2:U100').getValues();
  var leads  = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Email Scraper &   Verifier Custom').getRange('B2:D100').getValues();

  if (sendex > 0.8) {
    for (var i = 0;i<leads;i++)
      break;
    leads.CopyTo(sheet)     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. sendex is an array and can't have one single value, it evaluates to false and the function finishes
2. If it won't evaluate to false it calls a loop which immediately breaks and then it copies all leads to the output sheet.

Do you want to do something like:

```
for (var lead = 0; lead < leads.length; lead++){
  if (sendex[lead] > 0.8){
    sheet.push(leads[lead]);
  }
}
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Output Clean Data      to ESP').getRange(2,2,sheet.length,4).setValues(sheet)
```

?
(Be aware that this function will currently always get the 2:100 range and append and overwrite new scored leads but I'm not sure if you already took care of that in copyTo)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! However, I do get the following error now: "TypeError: Cannot find function append in object" 

Doesn't seem to recognize append in that context.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's push in JS. I changed the code accordingly.

Comment: Strange, this time I get not error but after running the function - nothing seems to happen (i.e. values are not transferred). Debugging via sheets script editor seems to just timeout, or appear and then disappear.

Comment: Can't fit the full code in here, so here's a screenshot.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_kS0U9qYC1peER4RXU4UUxOb28

Comment: The last function needs to call `setValues(sheet)` not `get values()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! The way I ended up getting it to work was with the following code. It worked better leaving the getrange values undefined in the variable and defining them later on.

destrow just manages blank lines and skips them.

```
function output() 
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Output Clean Data to    ESP');

var sendex = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Email Scraper &  Verifier Custom').getRange('U2:U100').getValues();
var leads = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Email Scraper & Verifier Custom')

var destRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < sendex.length; i++)  
{
if (sendex[i] > 0.74){

  var row = 2 + i;

  leads.getRange(row, 2, 1, 3).copyTo(sheet.getRange(destRow, 1, 1, 3),{contentsOnly:true})
  leads.getRange(row, 6, 1, 1).copyTo(sheet.getRange(destRow, 4, 1, 1),{contentsOnly:true})      

  destRow += 1;

}
 }
  {


 }

}
```